# Error while creating an angular application

Tags: json, angular, dependencies

1. I have installed node js and angular app
2. trying to create a new application using the below command ng new a3
   3 getting the below error

   `npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."},"devDependencies":'`

> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\BabuRajendra_P\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-12-14T10_56_51_267Z-debug.log
>   Package install failed, see above

can anyone please help

Comment: Hi Babu, Welcome to stackoverflow please post your full error message.

Comment: @FatemeFazli here is the full log

Comment: 2832 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."},"devDependencies":'
2832 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
2832 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
2832 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50
2832 verbose stack     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
2832 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
2833 verbose cwd D:\Angular_Tutorial\first-app

Comment: 2834 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
2835 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--quiet"
2836 verbose node v12.13.1
2837 verbose npm  v6.12.1
2838 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."},"devDependencies":'
2839 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: @BabuRajendra: There is also an `edit` button (at the bottom of your question).

Comment: Also add your package.json, please. Appears that you have some issue in you package-json